# What can we do to infer if a currently unmounted directory under / has ever been mounted? Thanks

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

Is there any way to check whether a directory has once been mounted? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want this info?

Comment: @ewwhite Coz I met a client who lost his data under /home directory. And he forgot whether he unconsciously mounted a disk on the directory earlier. I figured no way to confirm if he ever mounted any disk to this directory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are not guaranteed to find traces of any type of mount.
However, there are some usually-present indicators:

- systemd will log its mounts, try `zgrep -i mount /var/log/syslog*`
- most, but not all common filesystem drivers will spit out some diagnostics like `EXT4-fs (sda14): mounted filesystem without journal.`
- mounting over a non-empty directory may result in a warning
- external disks will have left syslog traces when attaching

You are probably more likely to find the directory in its real place. If its on the disk (`-o bind`) then there should be user-owned files in unusual places. If its an external disk, attaching/removing will have made the respective drivers spew out quite some informational wall of text.